# I have a couple of problems when I upgraded packages in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I have a couple of problems when I upgraded packages in my Flutter app.

Compiler message:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/country_pickers-1.3.0/lib/country_picker_dropdown.dart:151:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onTap'.
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart:784:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  DropdownButton({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

Comment: Have you fully restarted? After package upgrades/installs you need to fully stop execution and rebuild

Comment: Whenever you upgrade, make sure to run `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` for all updates to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fork](https://github.com/shadyshrif/country_pickers_backward_support) from the package `country_pickers` to solve this issue. They are depending on a newer version of flutter while I'm not planning to upgrade my app flutter version now. I'm using flutter version `1.12.13`

If you are directly depending on the package you can use my fork.

```
  country_pickers :
    git:
      url: git://github.com/shadyshrif/country_pickers_backward_support
      ref: 5d16109618f2a9bcc1ff49cfd6d53011f0217d67
```

If the package `country_pickers` is used by another package (you didn't add it to dependency by yourself) you can enforce flutter to replace the dependency using

```
dependency_overrides:
  country_pickers :
    git:
      url: git://github.com/shadyshrif/country_pickers_backward_support
      ref: 5d16109618f2a9bcc1ff49cfd6d53011f0217d67
```